# How do I create a new numpy array from an existing larger numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have an [8, 8] numpy array. I want to create a smaller [3,5] numpy array from a section of this array. I have no idea how to even begin this.

I need a kickstart to move further. Please help.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Click [edit] and add code that creates a 64-element array with `np.arange()`. The use `np.reshape()` to make it 8x8 and print what you have got. Then show which elements you want to create the smaller array from and show what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.